# Simple Pivot Query Help

Tags: php, mysql

Consider this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS pageviews 
FROM stats_hits 
WHERE pageID='1' AND entrytime>DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) 
GROUP BY DATE(`entrytime`) LIMIT 5
```

Returns hit counts for the last five days: something like:

```
11
12
18
15
5
```

How can I rewrite this query to return a horizontal result set?

```
11, 12, 18, 15, 5
```

Thanks!

EDIT: As a side problem, does anyone know how to tweak this query to display 0 for days with no hits? At the moment if there were no hits on a particular day, only 4 results are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.pageviews) AS pageviews
FROM
  (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS pageviews 
  FROM stats_hits 
  WHERE pageID='1' AND entrytime>DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) 
  GROUP BY DATE(`entrytime`) LIMIT 5
  ) s;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

If you want to always have 5 results, something like this ugly hack might work.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s2.pageviews) AS pageviews
FROM 
  (
  SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS pageviews 
    FROM stats_hits 
    WHERE pageID='1' AND entrytime>DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) 
    GROUP BY DATE(`entrytime`) LIMIT 5
    UNION ALL SELECT 0 AS pageviews
    UNION ALL SELECT 0 AS pageviews
    UNION ALL SELECT 0 AS pageviews
    UNION ALL SELECT 0 AS pageviews
    UNION ALL SELECT 0 AS pageviews
    ) s1
  ORDER BY pageviews = 0 ASC
  LIMIT 5) s2;
```

Another options is this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table LIKE SELECT 0 as pageviews;
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES (0),(0),(0),....,(0);
INSERT INTO temp_table 
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS pageviews 
  FROM stats_hits 
  WHERE pageID='1' AND entrytime>DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL x DAY) 
  GROUP BY DATE(`entrytime`) LIMIT x; //replace x with the number of days

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.pageviews) AS pageviews
FROM temp_table t
ORDER BY t.pageview = 0 ASC 
LIMIT x;  //replace x with the number of days
```

Comment: Thanks Johan - nice quick and dirty pivot technique. I'll remember this! I sometimes have to check the last 30 or 60 days so your hack above wont work unfortunately. Also it doesnt look as if it keeps the results in order which I probably need also. Thanks a lot for the help anyway.

Comment: @cronoklee, the `group by` sorts the results by `entrytime`. The `order by` in the middle subselect doesn't change that order, you can always add an `order by` in the inner or outer select though.

Comment: Wow looks great - thanks @Johan. I presume in `VALUES (0),(0),(0),....,(0);` I need to add a (0) for every day I want to count?